# How to mock callback functions with jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, callback, jestjs

I'm trying to mock a custom function with jest but I'm having problems with it.

This is my function:

```
export const resizeImage = (file, fileName, callback) => {
  const MAX_WIDTH = avatarImage.maxWidth;
  const MAX_HEIGHT = avatarImage.maxHeight;
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  img.onload = () => {
    const sizes = internalResizeImage(img, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT);

    canvas.width = sizes.width;
    canvas.height = sizes.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, sizes.width, sizes.height);
    return callback(dataURItoFile(canvas.toDataURL(), fileName));
  };
};
```

I called like this:

```
resizeImage(acceptedFiles[0], this.props.user.id, (res) => {
  //dostuff
});
```

In my test I'm mocking it like this:

```
let mockResizeImage = jest.fn();

jest.mock('../../utilities/imageUtils', () => ({
  resizeImage: () => mockResizeImage
}));
```

I want mockResizeImage to be a callback and then in my test change the returning values:

```
it('should call handleDrop and accept files', () => {
    //mockResizeImage.mockReturnValue('something');

    const instance = shallow(mockComponent()).instance();
    const acceptFilesMock = ['test'];

    instance.handleDrop(acceptFilesMock);

    expect(clickSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

If it were a promise, all good, but it's a callback and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can mock a module with a function that accepts the same parameter as your original one, and instantly call the callback:

```
jest.mock('../../utilities/imageUtils', () => ({
  resizeImage: (file, fileName, callback) => callback('someData')
}));
```

Btw. the way you mock the module in your question can't work because of the way `jest.mock` works. Even if you write it after the `let` statement, it will be hoisted to the top of the file when the test is been compiled. So the best way to mock the function with a spy would look like this:

```
import {resizeImage} from '../../utilities/imageUtils'

jest.mock('../../utilities/imageUtils', () => ({
  resizeImage: jest.fn((file, fileName, callback) => callback('someData'))
}));
```

Now you have the same behaviour as above but you can also test that `resizeImage` was called with the correct parameters.

As your last parameter is a function you can either just test for the 2 first params like this using [`mock.calls`](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockcalls):

```
expect(resizeImage.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('firstParameter')
expect(resizeImage.mock.calls[0][1]).toBe('secondParameter')
```

Or use a wildcard for the last parameter when using `toBeCalledWith` using [`expect.anything()`](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/expect.html#expectanything):

```
expect(resizeImage).toBeCalledWith('firstParameter', 'secondParameter', expect.anything());
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andreas! It works but I don't know how to test resizeImage import. Do I have to add a spider to it? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "test `resizeImage `"? Testing that `resizeImage ` was called with the correct parameter?

Comment: Yes, I did it that now by doing this: ```expect(resizeImage).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);```

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Is it ok if I just use `expect(resizeImage.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('firstParameter')` instead of a mock that calls the callback?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure when you call the actual function by passing the callback function as one of the arguments, that function is being called from inside the test block **like below**

```
function forEach(items, callback) {
  for (let index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
    callback(items[index]);
  }
}
const mockCallback = jest.fn((x) => x + 1);

test("fn", () => {
  forEach([0, 1, 2], mockCallback);
  expect(mockCallback.mock.calls.length).toBe(3);
});
```

**And not like below**

```
function forEach(items, callback) {
      for (let index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
        callback(items[index]);
      }
    }
const mockCallback = jest.fn((x) => x + 1);
forEach([0, 1, 2], mockCallback);
    
test("fn", () => {
   expect(mockCallback.mock.calls.length).toBe(3);
});
```