# How do you pass the res object into the callback function in a jest mock function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, jestjs

I am developing a webserver in nodejs and am currently trying to cover all branches with jest testing. I have this one function, logout, that takes in the req and res objects from express. I need to jest test inside the if statement.

```
// app.js
function logout(req, res) {

    // console.log(req.session.destroy.toString());
    req.session.destroy(function (err){

        if (err){

            console.error(err);
            res.sendStatus(500);

        }
        console.log('Logged out');
        res.redirect('/');

    });

}
```

```
// app.test.js
    let res = {sendStatus: jest.fn((inp) => inp)};
    let req = {
        session: { destroy: jest.fn((callback) => {

            callback('TEST_ERROR');

        })}
    };

    test('Test /logout error', async () => {

        await logout(req, null);
        expect(req.session.destroy.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);

    });
```

I have already searched for similar answers and the only topic I could find of any use was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43788028/how-to-mock-callback-functions-with-jest) which allowed me to get inside the if statement but it is now throwing the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendStatus' of null`.
Is there anyway I can allow the callback function access to the res I have defined within app.test.js? Any help or pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

## Solved

As plumthedev correctly pointed out, in my app.test.js, when I call loguout I was passing null which I had missed. As soon as I changed it to res it fixed my issue.

```
// app.test.js
test('Test /logout error', async () => {

    await logout(req, res);
    expect(req.session.destroy.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your *app.test.js* in **test()** you pass a *res* parameter as **null**. And you get a error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendStatus' of null` which is normally because you pass **null**. This callback is correct but wrong invoked. Try to pass a *res* like you pass a *req*.

Be sure to read about it:
Callbacks functions MDN (theory): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

Callback functions (FelDev on Medium - practice and theory): https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/callbacks-in-node-js-how-why-when-ac293f0403ca

Greetings, plum!

Comment: Thank you, yes it turned out I had simply missed that I was passing res as null. As soon as I changed null to res it fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest callback example looks like that: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)
Yu can easily pass some props :)

Comment: Link may expire after some time, please try to add code in your answer.